# Howto initialise char array style string in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a class which I'm serialising to send over a unix socket and it has to have a string which I've stored as a char array.  Can I initialise it in the constructor differently to how I've done it here?

```
typedef struct SerialFunctionStatus_t {
    SerialFunctionStatus_t() 
        : serial_rx_count(0), serial_tx_count(0), socket_rx_count(0), socket_tx_count(0) 
        { port[0] = '\0'; }
    uint32_t serial_rx_count;
    uint32_t serial_tx_count;
    uint32_t socket_rx_count;
    uint32_t socket_tx_count;
    char port[20];
} SerialFunctionStatus_t;
```

Comment: In C++, you don't need the "typedef".

Comment: Thanks for that BKB.  Can you tell I'm really a C programmer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `port()` in the initializer list.  This causes port to be 'value initialized' (12.6.2), which for arrays of builtins means zero initialized (8.5).

Comment: What are you talking about? port() is not in the initializer list. Or did he edit his post?